# RxAndroidBle - writeCharacterstics failing in android naugat

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-android, rxandroidble

I am trying using `RxAndroidBLE` API to scan, connect and do write operations on BLE device. I am using following code to do `writeCharacterstic` operation

```
bluetoothGattCharacteristics.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    final Disposable disposable = connectionObservable
            .firstOrError()
            .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(bluetoothGattCharacteristics, data))
            .subscribe(
                    characteristicValue -> {
                        onWriteSuccess();
                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        onWriteFailure(throwable);
                    }
            );
```

This code works fine in android 9 or above (Not tested on android 8). But on android 7, `writeCharacterstic` fails with error `com.polidea.rxandroidble2.exceptions.BleGattCallbackTimeoutException: GATT exception from MAC address F6:91:6D:C6:37:1F, with type BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_WRITE'}`

I using latest release of `RxAndroidBLE i.e. 1.11.1`. Please suggest ..

**Update**

on more looking into this, found that if device state is already bonded on connect (bluetooth device saved in phone paired device list), write operation failing.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I already have a problem of not sending any data to my device and I am looking for an example.

Comment: Have you tried to postpone writing to the characteristic by about 2 seconds? If not — could you try and report back? `connectionObservable.delay(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`